# difference between document.forms[0].onsubmit and jQuery("form").submit

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, document, invoke

Why does `#1` get called when the `__doPostback` (this dynamic JavaScript function created automatically by ASP.NET when HTML renders.. I think when Event Validation is turned on) is called, but `#2` does not get called.  Yet, both get called when a button is clicked?

#### #1

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit =
     function() {
     alert("called submit 1");
     jQuery("#<%=DDLUCSAddress.ClientID %>").children("option").each(function() {
     jQuery(this).remove();
   });
 };
```

#### #2

```
jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    alert("called submit 2");
    jQuery("#<%=DDLUCSAddress.ClientID %>").children("option").each(function() {
            jQuery(this).remove();
    });
});
```

---

Rendered HTML - If I do a Ctrl+K+D on this code, it exceeds the character limit for Stack Overflow, due to the spaces.  If you'd like to look at it formatted, place into Visual Studio and press `Ctrl+K+D`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="sessionRefresh" style="display:none">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" />
<form id="Form1" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="EditSampleDetails.aspx?LabAccessioningNumber=20120401-1&SampleTypeContext=247" method="post" name="Form1">
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=EXaDJPTWpPG72bTbiKNh_OuYVox46idcF5L2FHTyi19FoknASLIR-iSOhjjdC3Xa0OCTSAQepXg5UpNN1TPkcREtvcQ1&t=634208598757546466" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=4scrxOSLDbM-cgeLoXFnrTxM83c-T6NjCtRi_ghVZlXN0qjfjwNCtjtRWczFgkWux80g8Ip0p9JqPBJcPSlcT3N25CA1&t=634208598757546466" />
<script type="text/javascript" />
<div>
<div id="mainMenu" class="droplinetabs">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<table class="uIBoxStacked" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="uIBoxInternal" colspan="2">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="BxWizardTitle" style="border-color:LightSteelBlue;width:100%;">
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl01", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl02", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl03", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="leftNavigationCell" style="vertical-align:top;">
<td>
<td valign="top">
<table cellpadding="5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table cellpadding="5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<script type="text/javascript" />
<table class="uIBoxStacked" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="uIBoxInternal" colspan="2">
<table class="outerTableOfInputs" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="tableOfInputs" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="FullDataEntryEditor_UIBSampleInfo" style="border-color:LightSteelBlue;width:100%;">
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("FullDataEntryEditor$ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("FullDataEntryEditor$ctl01", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("FullDataEntryEditor$ctl02", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("FullDataEntryEditor$ctl03", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>

<table>
<script type="text/javascript" />
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Additional Client Number</td>
<td>
<input id="FullDataEntryEditor_TxtAdditionalClientNumber" class="LIMSFormField" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="FullDataEntryEditor$TxtAdditionalClientNumber">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="saveCancelDeleteOuter" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="EditObjectId986257676" type="hidden" value="" name="EditObjectId986257676">
<input id="CommandName986257676" type="hidden" value="" name="CommandName986257676">
<table class="uIBoxStacked" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="uIBoxInternal" colspan="2">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="FullDataEntryEditor_NMNotes_List_ListBox" style="border-color:LightSteelBlue;width:100%;">
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("FullDataEntryEditor$NMNotes$List$ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("FullDataEntryEditor$NMNotes$List$ctl01", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("FullDataEntryEditor$NMNotes$List$ctl02", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<a href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("FullDataEntryEditor$NMNotes$List$ctl03", "", true, "", "", false, true))'></a>
<table id="FullDataEntryEditor_NMNotes_List_ListGrid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" rules="all">
<tbody>
<tr class="columnHeader">
<tr style="background-color:Yellow;">
<td>
<a href="javascript:listCustomPostback(986257676,'Edit',129285);">bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</a>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="pdfDisplay"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" />
<input id="FullDataEntryEditor_HiddenSampleType" type="hidden" value="247" name="FullDataEntryEditor$HiddenSampleType">
<input id="FullDataEntryEditor_HiddenAJAXUCSAddressValue" type="hidden" value="7533" name="FullDataEntryEditor$HiddenAJAXUCSAddressValue">
<input id="FullDataEntryEditor_HiddenAJAXUCSAddressText" type="hidden" value="[7533] A1's Primary address, a1_primary_address, madison wi, usa 53719" name="FullDataEntryEditor$HiddenAJAXUCSAddressText">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="saveCancelDeleteOuter" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<script type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" />
</form>
<table class="copyright" align="center">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__doPostback` does the following:

```
theform.onsubmit();
```

This is taking the value of the `onsubmit` attribute and executing it.  Submit handlers attached with jquery are not set as attributes on the element so they will not fire when this is done.

EDIT:

The relevant piece of code from the jQuery source:

```
if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
    elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
} else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
    elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
}
```

This is how jquery attaches its events, not with the onsubmit attribute.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!  Is there a way to have jQuery have an event fire when __doPostback is called?

Comment: You can't set `onsubmit` directly on the jquery object, you need to do it on the dom element.  So you could do `jQuery("form")[0].onsubmit`.  But really if that's all you're doing, why not just skip the jquery on that part.

Answer (score 2):

- The first `document.forms[0].onsubmit` is not jQuery. It assigned to the first form in your document. It gets fired if you click the submit button on the first form
- The second `jQuery("form").submit` is jQuery but asigned to all `forms` on your document. It gets fired if you click the submit button on each form within your document

Comment: if jQuery("form") is assigned to all forms, why isn't it called when __doPostback is called?

Comment: Please provide more sourcecode. Because we need to know where the javascript source is placed.